# IdentityServer4 user session expired while cookie is present

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4

We are using

> Aspnetcore@3.1

with identityserver4 using **oidc-js** client for authentication with cookie authentication.
We are unable to achieve remember me functionality. Identity cookie is persisted but session is unable to validate from server side it redirects to login page.
How could user session invalidate server side?

Help needed configurations are default as **Quickstart**.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check Cookies is configured for sliding expiration.
if it is sliding expiration, then please check silent refresh token concept.
your Cookie and refresh token lifetime should be inline.

Comment: @Ravi AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifeTime= 2,592,000 and SlidingRefreshTokenLifeTIme = 1,296,000
And session is not more than 3 hours old.